# Unpacking python dictionaries, or list comprehension, or …

Tags: python, dictionary

```python
my_dict = { 1: 11, 2: 12, 3: 13 }
```

If I want to work on the list of keys from `my_dict` there appear to be (at least) three ways to do this in Python >3.5 (i.e. on or after [PEP 448](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/))

*List Comprehension:*

```python
[key for key in my_dict]
```

> [1, 2, 3]

*Unpacking:*

```python
[*my_dict]
```

> [1, 2, 3]

*Constructing a list from the view of the keys:*

```python
list(my_dict.keys())
```

> [1, 2, 3]

Are these three methods interchangeable?

I think

- `[key for key in my_dict]` is the most 'Pythonic',
- `[*my_dict]` is the most terse, and
- `list(my_dict.keys())` is the most readable.

Are there any technical reasons for choosing between these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These all accomplish the same thing.  For the last one, calling keys() is not required.  `list(my_dict)` will do the same thing.  It's  a little more clear if you call `keys()` explicitly so you might want to do it anyway.

The rest of this question is opinion-based.  While all are valid options, I think 1 & 3 are preferable for this use and #2 makes sense for unpacking into method calls.